# Create multiple fields on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create multiple fields when I enter a number to tell it how many to create... I have utilised some code that I have written previously but now it's no longer working.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="rows">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#rows').change(function() {
    var rows = $(this).val();

    for(i=0;i<=rows;i++) {
            $('#form').append('<div><input type="text" name="N' + i + '"></div>');
        $('#form').append('<div><select name="S'+ i +'"><option value="Text">Text</option><option value="editor">Editor</option></select></div>');
        $('#form').append('<div><input type="text" name="V' + i + '"></div>');
    }
  }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dc5665xk/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `ID` attribute is missing for `rows` element.
- There is no `form` element having `form` as ID
- Syntax error as closing braces were missing.

Note: `var` keyword was missing in `for-loop`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#rows').change(function() {
    var rows = $(this).val();
    for (var i = 0; i <= rows; i++) {
      $('#form').append('<div><input type="text" name="N' + i + '"></div>');
      $('#form').append('<div><select name="S' + i + '"><option value="Text">Text</option><option value="editor">Editor</option></select></div>');
      $('#form').append('<div><input type="text" name="V' + i + '"></div>');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Rayon, I dont get why this doesnt run on JS Fiddle